# The set of non-singleton orbits and the set of non-fixed elements of a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $X$ be a finite set and $\sigma$ a permutation of $X$. Let $s:\langle\sigma\rangle\backslash X\rightarrow X$ be a section of the canonical surjection of $X$ onto $\langle\sigma\rangle\backslash X$.

What can be said about the relation between the sets $\{x\in X\ |\ \sigma(x)\ne x\}$ and $\{Y\in\langle\sigma\rangle\backslash X\ |\ Y\ne\{s(Y)\}\}$?

I can obviously use the non-singleton orbits to uniquely decompose $\sigma$ into cycles. But is there a way to characterize the lengths and the number of these cycles in terms of the set $\{x\in X\ |\ \sigma(x)\ne x\}$?

For example, what does the cardinality of $\{x\in X\ |\ \sigma(x)\ne x\}$ tell me about the decomposition of $\sigma$ using elements of $\{Y\in\langle\sigma\rangle\backslash X\ |\ Y\ne\{s(Y)\}\}$?

Comment: It's of course clear that if $a_n$ is the number of orbits of cardinality $n$ (equivalently the number of $n$-cycles in the disjoint-cycle decomposition of $\sigma$), then $\#X = \sum_{n\ge1} na_n$ and $\#(\langle\sigma\rangle\backslash X) = \sum_{n\ge1} a_n$ (and the fixed points, whose number is $a_1$, can be subtracted from both sides if desired). I'm not sure there's any more information that can be gleaned in general.